# Page break using css based on the Page height

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a dynamic list to print and I need to set break pages when I reach the end of the A4 size and not the end of a table like the example.

Is it possible to set a page break based on the height of the page?

Actually I have:

```
@page 
{
   size: A4;
   margin: 0;
   page-break-before: always; 
}

@media print 
{
 .page 
  {
    margin: 0;
    border: initial;
    border-radius: initial;
    width: initial;
    min-height: initial;
    box-shadow: initial;
    background: initial;
    page-break-after: always;
    position: relative;
}

 .page-break    
 { 
    display: block; 
    page-break-before: always;
 }
}
```

And the dynamic view composed by two tables with dynamic rows so I never know where to "cut" the page:

```
<div class="page">

    @foreach(var dme in Model)
    {
        <table class="dme-table">
             <tr>
                 <th class="titulo" colspan="4">DME</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <th class="dme-table-num-th">Número</th>
                    <th>Data</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => dme.Numero)</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table class="carga-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Cargas</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="marcas">Marcas</th>
                </tr>

                @foreach(var carga in dme.Cargas)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => carga.Marcas)</td>
                    </tr>
                 }
            </table>

        </div>

        <div class="page-break"></div>
    }
</div>
```

Any ideia?

Thanks

Comment: you could try to check (if-,else-statement) the height of the page in @foreach(var carga in dme.Cargas)... if the height reaches your desired goal, set your pagebreak there else display your carga.Marcas

Comment: Hi thanks, but the foreach test is not made in the server side?

Comment: You seem to have an extra </div> just before the .page-break. Fix that and it might work

Answer (score 0):

I would not bother - different users will have different font stacks, paper sizes (think legal is standard in states). Modern browsers will likely do a better job so let them.

Chris Coyer has a [good screencast](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/52-building-a-print-stylesheet/) about basic use of print stylesheets if you have not seen it (you can skip the first 09:30 as it is mainly waffle).

Comment: Hi, thanks. It's a problem because I can't "break" the page when I reach the end of the paper, in the question example, I print a table per page leaving a big white space.

Comment: The browser should do it for you. You cannot know the client's setup: the fonts they do or do not have, the margin settings on their printer, their accessibility settings (may have forced large fonts as they are sight impaired). You can suggest page breaks at logical end of sections as you did above, but you cannot know where the physical page ends. It is a similar concept to responsive design - you cannot control if a user views your site on a phone, a tablet or a huuuuuuge desktop monitor.

Comment: In this case I know where it's gona be printed, I need to maximize print area and minimize paper used.